# Add bootstrap tooltip to dynamically created button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I dynamically create buttons like this:

```
var my_button = document.createElement('button');
my_button.setAttribute('id', "the_id");
```

I am trying to use Bootstrap tooltips with these buttons but I cannot get it to work.

```
my_button.setAttribute('data-toggle', 'tooltip');
my_button.setAttribute('data-placement', 'top');
my_button.setAttribute('title', 'this is my text');
```

In $(document).ready(function() I have

```
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
```

And to try and deal with the fact that the buttons are dynamically created I use:

```
$('body').tooltip({ selector: '[rel=tooltip]' });
```

I have sourced all the necessary bootstrap files, and tested the tooltip using text element tag, and that works fine.

When I hover over the button nothing happens.

Comment: Did you even bother reading my question? As plainly stated, this was already attempted.

Comment: $('body').tooltip({ selector: '[rel=tooltip]' });  // i think this is for bootstrap v2. Try $('body').tooltip({ selector: '[data-toggle="tooltip"]' }); instead. http://codepen.io/partypete25/pen/RaEEPj

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Call this script **after** you created dom elements :

```
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
```

Comment: Just had to use jquery to set the attributes first...then adding your line "after" as you said. Thank you!